# Mysql SELECT query HAVING combined with INNER JOIN WHERE not showing all requested data

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I've written a complex [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) query which is not returning all requested data. It seems like the INNER JOIN isn't working correctly.
This query does return the right result set, I'm just missing the columns from the joined table.

My Query:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, ( 6371 * acos( cos(radians(?) )
* cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
WHERE TABLE2.Col2 =? 
AND Table2.Col3 =?
HAVING distance < ? 
ORDER BY distance
```

My result only contains values from `Table1`, why isn't the INNER JOIN working?

EDIT:
I changed my Query to this based on P.Jairaj's answer, and this seems to work for me:

```
        SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3, T1.Col4, T1.Col5, T1.Col6, T2.Col1, 
        ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('?') ) * 
        COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS('?') ) + 
        SIN( RADIANS('?') ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
        FROM T1, T2
        WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
        AND T2.Col2 =  '?'
        AND T2.Col3 =  '?'
        HAVING distance <  '?'
        ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: try `left outer join`

Comment: The answers I got brought me closer to the solution but were not 100% correct. It seemed to me that if I accepted these as the answer it would confuse future visitors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t2.Col3, t1.Col4, t2.Col5, t2.Col6, ( 6371 * acos( cos(radians(?) )
* cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
Where t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
AND t2.Col2 =? AND t2.Col3 =?
AND distance < ? 
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This is actually working with HAVING distance instead of AND distance because it's not possible to use WHERE or AND for a pseudo column created by an AS statement. But can anybody explain me if this is the correct way of selecting from multiple columns or whether I need to use JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the second table on all of the selected items. For example, if you want something from `Table2` you would state that:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table2.Col1, Table2.Col2
```

For each column you state you should be explicit about table choice.

Answer (score -2):

try having in place of having and where means you can try

```
HAVING TABLE2.Col2 =? AND Table2.Col3 =? AND distance < ? ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: You replace `WHERE` with `HAVING`? That will not work, it'll throw a syntax error.